# Can't see video in scene background with scene kit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, avplayer

I'm trying to run a mp4 in the background of my scene with `sceneKit`. The video appears to be executing via print statements & the status bar showing ~50 fps. However when the app opens on the simulator - all I see is a black screen. I can get the video to run in a typical `AVPlayer` but I can't figure out how to connect it with Scene Kit.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var sceneView: SCNView!
//var scene: SCNScene!

var cameraNode: SCNNode!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the view's delegate
    //sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView = self.view as! SCNView

    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true

    // Create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene

    let movieFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "master", withExtension: "mp4")!
    let player = AVPlayer(url:movieFileURL)
    scene.background.contents = player
    sceneView.play(nil) //without this line the movie was not playing

    player.play()
}


override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

}
```

This is what I see when I open the app:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is running in the iOS Simulator, which uses OpenGL as shown in the statistics bar. In Xcode 11 and macOS Catalina it will use the Metal renderer and you should see the video.

If you run the app on an actual device the video should also appear.

---

> ```swift
> sceneView.play(nil) //without this line the movie was not playing
> ```

The [`rendersContinuously`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/2867339-renderscontinuously) API is slightly better to achieve the same effect, as it doesn't implicitly refer to animations.